# Bounding the probability of success of adding elements into a list

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, algorithms

Suppose $_1,…,_$ are lists with $n$ elements each. We use a fully independent hash function ℎ to compute a value for each element of each list. (We suppose the hash function returns a value uniformly at random from $[^2]$. Note also that two elements $x$, and $y$ where $x = y$ has $ℎ()=ℎ()$.) Let $_1,…,_$ be sublists with the smallest $$ elements *by computed hash value* in each list. Let $_1$ contain $L_1$. Define more $$s by: if $|_\cap _|</$, let $_{+1}=_\cup_$; and otherwise let $_{+1}=_$. What size of $$ will ensure with probability at least $1−1/^2$ that: If $|_\cap _|</$, then $|_\cap_|<1.1/$; and otherwise, $|_\cap_|>0.9/$? I am looking to minimize the size of $X$.

Edit: Above simplified problem suggested by Matt F. in the comments below.

Comment: So $X$ can depend on $n$, $r$, $c$ and $\epsilon$? That's a lot of variables. It would be easier to understand with a more concrete version of the problem where two of them are fixed, if you can find parameters that still give an interesting version of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the problem statement such that $c$ is gone and $\epsilon$ is some error bound that you can determine (instead of a parameter that is an input to the problem).

Comment: Does this shorter version miss anything essential, and if so why is the missing bit essential? Suppose $L_1, \dots, L_k$ are lists with $n$ elements each, and $M_1, \dots, M_k$ are sublists with the smallest $X$ elements in each list.

Let $C_1$ contain some elements from the lists. Define more $C$'s by: if $|C_i \cap M_i| < X/r$, let $C_{i+1} = C_i \cup L_i$; and otherwise let $C_{i+1} = C_i$.

What size of $X$ will ensure with probability at least $1 - 1/n^2$ that: If $|C_i \cap M_i| < X/r$, then $|C_i \cap L_i| < 1.1 n/r$; and otherwise, $|C_i \cap L_i| > 0.9 n/r$?

Comment: @MattF. No this doesn't miss anything. I would just add that we want to minimize the value of $X$. Feel free to update the question with this formulation. Otherwise I will update it tomorrow.

Comment: What are the random laws in your problem? $L_1,\cdots,L_k,M_1,\cdots,M_k,C_i$ are random ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! That's a very important part of the question that I accidentally left out in the revision. All elements are hashed using the same hash function and M_i is the X smallest elements of L_i by hash value. I've updated the question with this info. Notably this means that C and M_i are correlated.